# Calculate the average of each column in a row at the end

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get a calculation at the end of the table that averages each column. I can't seem to get my head working right on this.

This is my query:

```
SELECT profiles.id, min (total_connections_average) from profiles

inner join connections ON from_profile_id = profiles.id

    inner join (

        select sq.from_profile_id,

        count (sq.countn) as total_connections_average 
            from (

            select from_profile_id, cast (accepted_at as date), count (*) as countn from connections

            group by from_profile_id, cast (accepted_at as date)
            ) as sq

        group by sq.from_profile_id
        
            ) sq ON sq.from_profile_id = profiles.id
    
where profiles.id in ('1','2','3','4','25','26')
    
group by profiles.id
```

Resulting data from the query:

| id | min |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 31 |
| 2 | 11 |
| 3 | 21 |
| 4 | 8 |
| 25 | 9 |
| 26 | 6 |

I'd like to have a row at the end with an average calculation for each column e.g.:

| id | min |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 31 |
| 2 | 11 |
| 3 | 21 |
| 4 | 8 |
| 25 | 9 |
| 26 | 6 |
| 10.16666667 | 14.33333333 |

Much appreciate any help.

Comment: which mysql version are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best I can think of is a union with the previous query. This is a quick fix what I came up

```
SELECT profiles.id, min (total_connections_average) min from profiles

inner join connections ON from_profile_id = profiles.id

inner join (

select sq.from_profile_id,

count (sq.countn) as total_connections_average
from (

select from_profile_id, cast (accepted_at as date), count (*) as countn from connections

group by from_profile_id, cast (accepted_at as date)
) as sq

group by sq.from_profile_id

) sq ON sq.from_profile_id = profiles.id

where profiles.id in ('1','2','3','4','25','26')

group by profiles.id

#this is union for average last column

union

select avg(agg.id), avg(agg.min)
from (
SELECT profiles.id, min (total_connections_average) min from profiles

inner join connections ON from_profile_id = profiles.id

inner join (

select sq.from_profile_id,

count (sq.countn) as total_connections_average
from (

select from_profile_id, cast (accepted_at as date), count (*) as countn from connections

group by from_profile_id, cast (accepted_at as date)
) as sq

group by sq.from_profile_id

) sq ON sq.from_profile_id = profiles.id

where profiles.id in ('1','2','3','4','25','26')

group by profiles.id
) agg
```